# I get the following error when I run this code netlogo

Tags: netlogo

my model 
of netlogo

```
globals [ mejor-recorrido
          coste-mejor-recorrido ]
breed [ nodos nodo ]
breed [ hormigas hormiga ]
links-own [ coste
            feromona ]       
hormigas-own [ recorrido
               coste-recorrido ]
to setup
  __clear-all-and-reset-ticks
  set-default-shape nodos "circle"
  ask patches [set pcolor white]
  crea-nodos
  crea-aristas
  crea-hormigas
  set mejor-recorrido camino-aleatorio
  set coste-mejor-recorrido longitud-recorrido mejor-recorrido
end

to crea-nodos
  ask n-of num-nodos patches
  [  
    sprout-nodos 1
    [
      set color blue + 2
      set size 2
      set label-color black
      set label (word "Ciudad-" who)
    ]
  ]
end

to crea-aristas
  ask nodos
  [ 
    create-links-with other nodos
    [
     ; hide-link
      set color red
      set coste link-length 
      set feromona random-float 0.1
    ]
  ]
  ask links [
    if(feromona < 0.05) [die] ]
  let max-coste max [coste] of links
  ask links
  [
    set coste coste / max-coste
  ]
end

to crea-hormigas
  create-hormigas num-hormigas [
    hide-turtle
    set recorrido []
    set coste-recorrido 0
  ]
end

to reset
  ask hormigas [die]
  ask links [
    hide-link
    set feromona random-float 0.1
  ]
  crea-hormigas
  set mejor-recorrido camino-aleatorio
  set coste-mejor-recorrido longitud-recorrido mejor-recorrido  
  clear-all-plots
end

to go
  no-display
  ask hormigas [
    set recorrido generar-recorrido
    set coste-recorrido longitud-recorrido recorrido 
    if coste-recorrido < coste-mejor-recorrido [
      set mejor-recorrido recorrido
      set coste-mejor-recorrido coste-recorrido
    ]
  ]

  actualiza-feromona
  tick
  display
end

to-report camino-aleatorio
  let resp [self] of nodos
  report lput (first resp) resp
end

to-report generar-recorrido
  let origen one-of nodos
  let nuevo-recorrido (list origen)
  let resto-nodos [self] of nodos with [self != origen]
  let nodo-actual origen

  while [not empty? resto-nodos] [
    if (self = origen) [
        ask hormigas [die]
      ]
    let siguiente-nodo elige-siguiente-nodo nodo-actual resto-nodos
    set nuevo-recorrido lput siguiente-nodo nuevo-recorrido
    set resto-nodos remove siguiente-nodo resto-nodos
    set nodo-actual siguiente-nodo
  ]
  set nuevo-recorrido lput origen nuevo-recorrido

  report nuevo-recorrido
end

to-report elige-siguiente-nodo [nodo-actual resto-nodos]
  let probabilidades calcula-probabilidades nodo-actual resto-nodos
  let rand-num random-float 1
  report last first filter [first ? >= rand-num] probabilidades
end

to-report calcula-probabilidades [nodo-actual resto-nodos]
  let pt map [([feromona] of ? ^ alpha) * ((1 / [coste] of ?) ^ beta)]
             (map [arista nodo-actual ?] resto-nodos)
  let denominador sum pt
  set pt map [? / denominador] pt
  let probabilidades sort-by [first ?1 < first ?2]
                             (map [(list ?1 ?2)] pt resto-nodos)
  let probabilidad-normalizada []
  let ac 0
  foreach probabilidades [
    set ac (ac + first ?)
    set probabilidad-normalizada lput (list ac last ?) probabilidad-normalizada
  ]
  report probabilidad-normalizada  
end

to actualiza-feromona
  ;; Evapora la feromona del grafo
  ask links [
    set feromona (feromona * (1 - rho))
  ]
  ask hormigas [
    let inc-feromona (100 / coste-recorrido)
    foreach aristas-recorrido recorrido [
      ask ? [ set feromona (feromona + inc-feromona) ]    
    ]
  ]
end

to-report aristas-recorrido [nodos-recorrido]
  report map [arista (item ? nodos-recorrido)
                     (item (? + 1) nodos-recorrido)] (n-values num-nodos [?])
end

to-report arista [n1 n2]
  report (link [who] of n1 [who] of n2)
end

to-report longitud-recorrido [nodos-recorrido]
  report reduce [?1 + ?2] map [[coste] of ?] (aristas-recorrido nodos-recorrido)
end
```

Comment: Please post the error that you're getting.

Comment: OF expected input to be a link agentset or link but got NOBODY instead.

Comment: Which line is it tell you the error is on?

Comment: let pt map [([feromona] of ? ^ alpha) * ((1 / [coste] of ?) ^ beta)] (map [arista nodo-actual ?] resto-nodos)

Comment: and here--->  report reduce [?1 + ?2] map [[coste] of ?] (aristas-recorrido nodos-recorrido)

Comment: kingrif, the information that Bryan is asking for belongs in the original question, and it would be better to edit your question to add it, rather than leaving this crucial information in comments.

Answer (score 2):

I added

```
print aristas-recorrido nodos-recorrido
```

as the first line after `to-report longitud-recorrido [nodos-recorrido]`.  This shows that `aristas-recorrido nodos-recorrido` returns a list in which some of the elements are `nobody`.  That's what's processed by one of the lines that is generating the error you mentioned.

I believe that the problem is that in the definition of `aristas-recorrido`,

```
to-report aristas-recorrido [nodos-recorrido]
  report map [arista (item ? nodos-recorrido)
                     (item (? + 1) nodos-recorrido)]
             (n-values num-nodos [?])
end
```

`arista` attempts to report the link between subsequent `nodo` turtles in the list `nodos-recorrido`, but some of the pairs of `nodos` are not linked.

It looks to me like the procedure `crea-aristas` links every `nodo` with every other `nodo`, but then removes links with `feromona < 0.05`.  After that, not all `nodos` are linked.  Since `nodos-recorrido` above is just a randomly-ordered list of `nodos` (is this right?), some of the pairs of `nodos` are not linked, and thus `arista` returns `nobody` rather than a link for some pairs.  Then this leads to the error in `longitud-recorrido`.

(I didn't investigate the other line that's generating the error, but I think you'll have enough information to track down that error now.)

Comment: Thinks you,yes the error because some nodos are not conected,but i have to do it like that ,i have to resolved in a no complete graph ,but i dont konw how :(( ...solution :One of them is  kill the ant who do that and create it again to start again.

Comment: You could use `filter`  in addition to `map` in order to remove the `nobody`s, or you could probably use `reduce` to perform both the `map` and `filter` steps at once.  It may be useful to add a test to `aristas-recorridos` for `nobody`s.  I don't know whether any of these suggestions will help to accomplish your goals, however.